# Interpolating Columnar Data

Tags: csv, unix, awk, interpolation

I am trying to find a way to interpolate between two lines of data in a CSV file, likely using `awk`. Right now, each line represents a data point at Hour 0 and Hour 6. I am looking to fill in missing hourly data between Hour 0 and Hour 6.

**Current CSV**

```
lat,lon,fhr
33.90000,-76.50000,0
34.20000,-77.00000,6
```

**Expected Interpolated Output**

```
lat,lon,fhr
33.90000,-76.50000,0
33.95000,-76.58333,1
34.00000,-76.66667,2
34.05000,-76.75000,3
34.10000,-76.83333,4
34.15000,-76.91667,5
34.20000,-77.00000,6
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an awk file that should achieve this

```
# initialize lastTime, also used as a flag to show that the 1st data line has been read
BEGIN { lastTime=-100 }
# match data lines
/^[0-9]/{
   if (lastTime == -100) {
      # this is the first data line, print it
      print;
   } else {
      if ($3 == lastTime+1) {
         # increment of 1 hour, no need to interpolate
         print;
      } else {
        # increment othet than 1 hour, interpolate
        for (i = 1 ; i < $3 - lastTime; i = i + 1) {
            print lastLat+($1-lastLat)*(i/($3 - lastTime))","lastLon+($2-lastLon)*(i/($3 - lastTime))","lastTime+i
         }
         print;
      }
   }
   # save the current values for the next line
   lastTime = $3;
   lastLon = $2;
   lastLat = $1;

}
/lat/{
   # this is the header line, just print it
   print;
}
```

Run it as

```
 awk -F, -f test.awk test.csv
```

I assume your third column has integral values.